# $P(x)$ is a polynomial with leading coefficient $1$ and degree 2009 such that $P(0)=2008,~P(1)=2007,\cdots,P(2008)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> $P(x)$ is a polynomial with leading coefficient $1$ and degree 2009 such that $P(0)=2008,~P(1)=2007,~P(2)=2006,\cdots,P(2008)=0$. Find $P(x)$.

Using remainder theorem, If $P(x)$ is divided by $x-0$, the remainder is $P(0)=2008$.
$$P(x)=xQ(x)+2008$$

How should I proceed?

Comment: Is this (contest-math), by any chance?  (If so, obviously a few years old, but I thought I'd ask.)

Comment: @BrianTung this is not the full question. Here is the actual question: Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $2009$ & leading coefficient unity such that $P(0) = 2008, P(1) =2007, P(2) = 2006,..., P(2008) = 0$ & the value of $P(2009)= n!+a$ where n & a are natural number, then the value of $(n+a)$ is?

Comment: I got it from my test paper.

Comment: One way to start to think about a problem like this is to ask yourself if the 2009 matters. Can you state and solve the analogous problems when you replace 2009 by 1, 2 and 3? If so, that may help you see a general phenomenon. Note: I haven't tried this. I'm just suggesting a strategy.